# What is the theory behind port forwarding when using P2P programs

Tags: p2p, router, ports

Every time I use a different router and different P2P program, I get the same problem - port forwarding. I then usually read random values of ports(TCP, UDP, whatever) and paste it into random places in my router setttings page and repeat this process until the damn thing starts working. As I am a bit tired of doing that i would like to understand the theory behind it a little bit, so that I can put the right things in right places immediately. Could anybody just explain it briefly to me in a few words? Apologies for lengthy description of the problem, but I didn't know how to describe the level of understanding that I am talking about in a more concise way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the router hides you from the outer world, so you can only make outgoing connections, for which router takes care of sending your requests to the outer world, receiving responses, and sending those back to you. No one can send a packet to you unless you have specifically asked for it—i.e. you can only receive *responses*.

In case on p2p, the ability to send packets to your machine is important if not vital. So what you do is ask router to forward (here! that's where the word comes from) all incoming packets to port X to your machine, port X.

Answer (score 0):

Originally IP addresses were provided per device, now-a-days we tend to have 1 IP address per household (unless your doing something crazy), also called your external IP. Your external IP is your connection to the world via your router, but each computer within your network has it's own IP (called internal IP). Port forwarding allows the external world to establish communications with a specific computer.

A web server is a simple example, web services typically rely on port 80, what-if in your network you had 4 computers, 1 of which was your web server. How would the outside world know which PC to contact? Port Forwarding allows you to tell your router to direct internet traffic to that server.